# savetxt How change the type from float64 to int or double

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have been trying to use the `savetxt` function in numpy. The problem I am running into is that even thought I define my variables accordingly, i.e. int() or double(), the text file i am getting out has floats in them. How can I change that?

Input is as follows: `pNoise=[int(i), around(pNoise[0], decimals=3), around(pNoise[1], decimals=3), around(pNoise[2], decimals=3)]`

savetxt line is as follows: `savetxt(noutF, pNoisetot)`

What I expect is: `0 1.567 8.865` instead I get `0.000000000000000000e+00 1.015909999999999940e+02 2.600000000000000089e-01`

Comment: What's the difference between `float64` and `double`?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you have the wrong format string. Show us your complete `savetxt` call with a sample of its output and a sample of what you expect.

Comment: Input is as follows: pNoise=[int(i), around(pNoise[0], decimals=3), around(pNoise[1], decimals=3), around(pNoise[2], decimals=3)]
savetxt line is as follows: savetxt( noutF ,pNoisetot)
@Gabe

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can define how the output has to be formatted with the `fmt` parameter of `np.savetxt`, e.g.:

- for floats rounded to five decimals:

  ```
    np.savetxt("file.txt", output, fmt='%10.5f', delimiter='\t')
  ```
- for integers:

  ```
    np.savetxt("file.txt", output, fmt='%i', delimiter='\t')
  ```

Here you can find more information about the possibilities of `fmt`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: Thanks I read the documentation beforehand, but my problem is that I actually am trying to ahve something like 
int(i) double() double()
@joris

Comment: If you want different columns have a different format, you also can specify this. In your case this would be: `fmt='%i %10.3f %10.3f'`

Answer (score 5):

In case you want to specify the number of decimals in the float the

```
np.savetxt("file.txt", output, fmt='%10.5f', delimiter='\t')
```

7 decimals in this case

```
np.savetxt("file.txt", output, fmt='%10.7f', delimiter='\t')
```

Basically, fmt = %10.Yf' where Y specifies the number of decs.